# How can i Write a custom Enable annotation for Interceptor in Spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to write a custom enable annotation to enable a Interceptor for a Spring Boot app.

This is my code,

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomInterceptor interceptor;

    @Override
      public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

}
```

**Interceptor**

```
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {

        System.err.println("Executed!!!afterCompletion");

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3)
            throws Exception {
        System.err.println("Executed!!!postHandle");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Custom Annotation**

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Import(CustomConfig.class)
public @interface EnableCustomConfig {

}
```

I want to enable this interceptor only if this annotation

> @EnableCustomConfig

is present in the main class,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCustomConfig
public class CustomEnableApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomEnableApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve in spring boot? If yes, please can you let me know how to.

Comment: Did my example answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options here. First, I think I'd skip the annotation completely. You could simply extend the interface:

```
public CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptor {}
```

Have your desired Interceptor implement this interface, and use `ApplicationContext` to determine which Spring beans implement this interface:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    Map<String, CustomInterceptor> interceptors = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CustomInterceptor.class);
    for(CustomInterceptor interceptor : interceptors.values()){
          registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

If you're set on using an annotation, you can use what's essentially identical logic to the above. You'd get all beans implementing the `HandlerInterceptor` interface, and then check their annotations. You can check a bean's annotations this way:

```
public boolean isAnnotatedWithMyAnnotation(Class clazz){
    return clazz.getAnnotation(EnableCustomConfig.class) == null ? false : true;
}
```